# How to get "Messages Inbox" styled Table Cell formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Im trying to format my table cells to look similar to the ones in the Messages Inbox on the iPhone,

basically trying to achieve:

Header       - Header 2

Sub Title

Answer (score 0):

In short, you want to create a custom `UITableViewCell' ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)). I typically use Interface Builder, but you can also do it all in code if you prefer.